# Given an ID column, a month/year column and three other columns containing numeric values, how do I merge by ID and month/year?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The Excel sheet has

- Column A: ID (e.g. 300312)
- Column B: Month/year (e.g. Mar-19)
- Column C: Transaction code (e.g. CODE1000)
- Column D: Payable amount 1-30 days (contains numeric values)
- Column E: Payable amount 31-60 days (contains numeric values)

What I want is a view of the data by the customer ID (say, 300312), and ensuring that each row contains only one of each possible month period. Right now, the problem is that the data can look like this (say I filtered by ID 300312:  [image]

As you can see, in ID 300312, there are two rows with the same month-year, because there have been two different transactions. I want to have it so that the transaction codes have no effect, and compressing each occurrence of "Mar-18" into one, by summing the numeric columns. So in this case, it should rather look like this: [image]

The transaction code has been removed, and the numeric columns have been summed up.   I would like to do this for every single ID.

Is there a clean/fast way to do this? Thank you for any help, and let me know if there are any questions you have for me.

Comment: Sorry, it keeps saying "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut.". I'm trying to make it neater for the reader.

Comment: You can show that using [PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

Comment: Is there a way without a Pivot Table? I've tried that but it doesn't give me the view in the second picture. I've also tried doing Consolidate Data but that only works on **one** key column, not two (in this case).

Comment: For anyone interested, a simple solution is to make a helper column (say column F). Then in F2, I let the formula be "= A2 & B2". Then I can use the Consolidate function on column F, and work backwards to get the correct "A2" and "B2" values.

Answer (score 1):

An example of a pivot with data from above pictures:

[image]
I think the result looks very similar to your 'desired output'.

Comment: Thanks. I actually just figured out a roundabout way without pivot tables too, but I still appreciate it.